# How to programmatically drag and drop a Sprite in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface, events

I need some actionscript code to simulate the dragging and dropping of a Sprite, I was wondering if it is possible to do so? if it is how?

For example to simulate a click on a Sprite I can achieve with the following line of code.

```
sprite.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

Comment: Can you explain what is this for? It's sounds like you doing smth wrong.

Comment: I'm writing some test code to test the UI, I need to drag the indicator (an Image) on an indicator bar.

Comment: I think it's wierd that Sprite has startDrag() and stopDrag() methods but no event dispatched. It would be nice to have at least dragStart and dragComplete events for Sprite.

Comment: @zdmytriv: Yes, but usually you know when your Sprites start and stop dragging because you have to place calls to the startDrag() and stopDrag() functions manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do something like this:

```
mySprite.addEventListener("mouseDown", mouseDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener("mouseUp", mouseUpHandler);
protected function mouseDownHandler (e:MouseEvent):void{
   e.target.startDrag();
}
protected function mouseDownHandler (e:MouseEvent):void{
   e.target.stopDrag();
}
```

You can pass 2 arguments to the startDrag method, the first is a boolean to lock to center, the second is a Rectangle-object for boundary-points.

And for a more controlled behavior you can do something like this instead:

```
mySprite.addEventListener("mouseDown",
mouseDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener("mouseUp", mouseUpHandler);
protected function mouseDownHandler (e:MouseEvent):void{
   stage.addEventListener("mouseMove",
mouseMoveHandler);
}
protected function mouseDownHandler (e:MouseEvent):void{
   stage.removeEventListener("mouseMove",
mouseMoveHandler);
}
protected function mouseMovehandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
  mySprite.x=mouseX;
  mySprite.y=mouseY;
}
```

(haven't tested the code so there might be some small syntax-error or something)

Comment: I know this is like five years later but you may have forgotten to edit the second `mouseDownHandler` to `mouseUpHandler`

Answer (score 0):

For AIR [Sprite Class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Sprite.html#eventSummary) has nativeDragStart, nativeDragOver, nativeDragEnter, nativeDragExit, nativeDragUpdate. So you can dispatch these events.

For Flex, object has to be instance of [UIComponent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#eventSummary).